# SQLiteMetro Windows8 db not storing data

Tags: sqlite, windows-8

I have two questions.

1. How can I get the SQLite Db to store data?  The db is created and I can find the db at its FilePath location, but I never see any data.
2. How do I change the location to save the data in a local folder, not in the Users... appdata folder?

Here is my code:

```
        Database db = new Database(Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path,"alpha2.db"));
  //   Database db = new Database("c:\\Projects\\alpha2.db");

        Statement stm;
        stm = db.PrepareStatement("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, age INTEGER, data BLOB)");
        stm.Execute();
        stm.Dispose();

        stm=db.PrepareStatement("INSERT INTO person(name,age VALUES(?,?)");
        stm.BindParamText(1,"John Doe");
        stm.BindParamInt(2,35);

        stm.Execute();
        stm.Dispose();

        long insertRowId = db.LastInsertRowId;

        stm=db.PrepareStatement("SELECT * FROM person");
            while(stm.GetNextRow())
            {
                int id=stm.GetIntAt(0);
                string name=stm.GetTextAt(1);
                textBlock1.Text=name.ToString();

            }

        stm.Dispose();
        db.Dispose();
```

TIA, this has been a two-day head banger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax on your insert query looks wrong.  It should be more like ...

```
INSERT INTO person(name,age) VALUES(?,?)
```

(Added a close paren after age.)

You can't write to an arbitrary location on the user's drive from a Metro Style app.  LocalFolder is your best bet.

Edit for comment:  Check out [Tim's article](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/05/20/using-sqlite-in-metro-style-app.aspx) on Sqlite for syntax for local folder.

Comment: Thanks JP, that fixed it.  :)  What would be the syntax for using the LocalFolder?